# Sending an internet radio singal from my hifi to a portable

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-radio

I'm just about to set myself up with a wireless network in my house. This is so that I can intregate an internet radio into my hifi system.

What I would love to do is to listen to the radio in another room of the house. I also have a little portable radio/cd player that has a USB port on the front.

Is there something I could buy which would allow me to listen to the radio through my portable in another room? I do realize that I could solve this problem by buying some wireless portable speakers, however I just wondered if anybody knew another way i.e. bluetooth or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a usb stick that streams data from a WIFI Connections, there are some products announced and some on the market. I've never used one of them, but I heard about them and some comments suggest they also work.

- http://www.infinitec.com/ium_drive/features.php
- http://hsti.com/wirelessmediastick/overview

For my opinion it's not worth the price, better buy a Streaming Radio from the different suppliers. Nearly every network manufacturer has something like this in his collection.

The advantage of using this USB Stick, you have radio/CD/Streaming Radio in one device.

Comment: The problem with these devices is that they work by presenting a file listing (and the infinitec one says it uses the laptop's wireless). The OP wants to share internet radio, which implies an audio source, not a file (if I read it correctly?).

Comment: You could save the radiostream live to mp3 and then play it with this sticks, but it's all tricky and there is no good solution in this.